# Can you intercept CDP commands from puppeteer without actually executing them on the page?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'd like to be able to leverage puppeteer to abstract click, scrolls, screenshots, etc, but pass the raw CDP commands generated by Puppeteer to another service. Similar to how [DevTools Protocol Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/experimental-features/#protocol-monitor), but from within a nodejs application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the deal: Puppeteer does its magic by sending CDP commands to a Chrome or Chromium browser. But intercepting these commands right before they hit the browser, that's a bit trickier. Puppeteer doesn't have a built-in way to just intercept and log these commands without executing them.

However, you're not totally out of luck. You could try a workaround:

Custom Puppeteer: You might need to modify Puppeteer's internals to intercept these commands. This means diving into Puppeteer's source code and tweaking it to log the commands it sends. It's a bit of a deep dive, though.

Proxy Server: Another way could be setting up a proxy server between Puppeteer and the browser. This server could catch the CDP commands, log them, and then choose whether to pass them on to the browser or not.

Both of these methods require some extra setup and a good grasp of how Puppeteer and the DevTools Protocol work.

If you're just looking to see what commands are being sent, for learning or debugging, you might want to run Puppeteer with the `--verbose` flag or check out the `puppeteer-core` library, which gives you a bit more control over the browser connection.

Hope this gives you a starting point!